# How to connect to DB2 database from Power bi desktop and when DB2 is hosted in a VM with port is SSL enabled?

Tags: ssl, db2, powerbi

I have my Data in a DB2 hosted in a VM which has the port with SSL enabled 50444. When I use Power BI Desktop to connect to DB2 DB using Microsoft driver , I get this error:
[image: Connection error]
DB2 DBA has given me CACERTS (ARM file), which I used the Keystore command and updated my Java JRE folder. Not sure what else to be done or if Microsoft has different folder to update the SSL certificate etc..
Can someone help me to resolve, if you had faced a similar issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Additionally, according to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-source-prerequisites  , the powerbi needs the "ADO.Net client from IBM (part of the IBM data server driver package)" to be able to connect to Db2. If you are using that, then it is not jdbc (i.e. no jre), and the instructions vary with the exact version of the IBM Db2-client that you have installed (if any).

Comment: If you looked up the error codes you get, you'd see that your connection is timing out. You don't even get to the point where the SSL session is being established, so you need to correct the network problem first.

Comment: Thanks Mao and Mustaccio. I had downloaded the Data Server Driver package from IBM and still it did not help. May be its not reaching the SSL session yet.